# In an eclipse plugin: How can I programmatically highlight lines of codes in the java editor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor

I am trying to develop an eclipse plugin that does some documentation check on java code and highlights some lines of code in the editor.

To achieve my goal, I DON'T want to create a new editor in eclipse, I simply want to extend the default java editor to draw a line under (or highlight) the methods that do not satisfy some set of predetermined requirements.

Do I need to create a PresentationReconciler? If yes, how do I make the JDT or workbench use my reconciler.

I have never done plugin development and this is my first attempt.

Comment: BTW you should read into JDT code, it already does many checks on the code and there should be a way for a plug-in to hook into that subsystem. Or at least get inspired.

Comment: @Kos, is it possible to highlight javadoc comments? If I can get past this huddle then I can try navigating myself towards achieving my goal.

Comment: I found this link really helpful [http://cubussapiens.hu/tag/markers/](http://cubussapiens.hu/tag/markers/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several starting points for you:

- [**Annotations**](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_annotations.htm?cp=2_0_13_3) are an UI feature of **JFace's text editor** that allows you to visually mark some places in an open editor.
- [**Markers**](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-11.htm?cp=0_2_6) are a **Workbench** feature, more high-level. They are generic "objects that may be associated with Workbench resources", and they can display in several places: in text editors (as annotations) or in the Problems view, for example.

Depending on what you want to do, you would plug in your plug-in into extension points related to either of those.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse Java editor is located in the `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor` package.

The "internal" in the package name means that the Eclipse development team can change how the Java editor works with new revisions.

Comment: How do I go about this? Am I meant to extend `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor` using "Extensions"?

Comment: @Lai: You're not meant to extend the Java editor at all.  If you want to modify the Java editor, you can set up the complete Eclipse source code as an Eclipse project.

Comment: While the Java editor is "internal", the editor itself can be extended through plug-in extension points just like any other part of Eclipse

Comment: @Kos: Feel free to outline the steps of using extension points to highlight additional Java lines, as the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this help page: [Juno Help on syntax highlighting](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_highlighting.htm?cp=2_0_13_6)

At the end of the page, it describes how to dynamically add a PresentationReconciler, which is used for syntax highlighting. See if that fits the problem that you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have a plugin project.

In your plugin.xml, open the tab `Extensions`, click `Add...`, search for `org.eclipse.ui.editors`, then you should see a template named `Editor`, which will produce a simple xml editor to experiment and play with. Also, you will be able to see the needed structure to define a custom editor.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This one extends the standard eclipse editor i guess. If you want to extend another one, you'll need their respective extension point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have a need for this, but you are going to want to use Annotations to keep track of what parts of the editor you need to highlight.

For actually doing the graphical effect of highlighting, you could do syntax highlighting via a PresentationReconciler, but I have no experience with that.

We used a technique we borrowed from http://editbox.sourceforge.net/, replacing the background image of the editor Shell.  Its open source, so check it out.  (Our code might also help -- its at https://github.com/IDE4edu/EclipseEditorOverlay )