# Eclipse PDE: StyleRange background colour disappears after a second

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, background-color, pde

I am currently developing an Eclipse plugin that colours lines of code, as well as braces and such.

I have everything working dynamically, I.E., if code gets changed, the line colours get updated accordingly.

**However, as soon as a line is coloured, after a bout a second it 'resets' and removes all colour.**

This is the event listener that checks if the user's source code has been modified.

```
    private void textModifiedListener() {
    for (IEditorPart editorPart : getCurrentEditorParts()) {
        editorText = editorPart.getAdapter(Control.class);
        if (editorText instanceof StyledText) {
            styledText = (StyledText) editorText;
            styledText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
                @Override
                public void modifyText(ModifyEvent event) {
                    //Source Code Modified.
                    Colour();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I then colour single characters like this:

```
    public void ColourCharacter(ColourObject colourOject, int characterIndex) {
    /* Given the colour and the character index, colour the given brace. */
    if (isColouringEnabled) {
        System.out.println("[ColourCode]:\tColourCharacter.");
        style = new StyleRange();
        style.start = characterIndex;
        style.length = 1;
        style.background = new Color(Display.getCurrent(), colourOject.getRed(), colourOject.getGreen(), colourOject.getBlue());
        if (editorText instanceof StyledText) {
            styledText.setStyleRange(style);
        }
    }
}
```

These methods are used to obtain the IEditorParts.

```
    /* Obtain the current workbench window. */
public synchronized static IWorkbenchWindow getActiveWorkbenchWindow() {
    return PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
}

/* Obtain the current editor reference. */
public synchronized static IEditorReference[] getCurrentEditorReferences() {
    return getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getEditorReferences();
}

/* Obtain the current editor parts. */
public synchronized List<IEditorPart> getCurrentEditorParts() {
    List<IEditorPart> editorParts = new ArrayList<IEditorPart>();
    for (IEditorReference editorReference : getCurrentEditorReferences()) {
        IEditorPart editor = editorReference.getEditor(true);
        if (editor != null) {
            editorParts.add(editor);
        }
    }
    return editorParts;
}
```

I have been stuck with this issue for an entire day now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are leaking `Color` objects in this code. If you create a `Color` you must arrange to `dispose` it when you are done. You should also reuse the `Color` object for a particular color as the number of `Color` objects may be limited by the OS.

Comment: The ColourObjects you see are objects I created. Or are you referring to other `Color` objects?

Comment: `style.background = new Color(....`

Comment: Thanks. However, I still have the same issue of colours disappearing after about a second :/

Comment: This does not solve that issue I was just pointing out a flaw in the code (which is why it was a comment).

Answer (score 2):

Most existing editors have their own system of styling the text they are managing. This usually uses the JFace `SourceViewerConfiguration`, `Reconciler`, `PresentationReconciler`, `IPresentationDamager`, `IPresentationRepairer` classes among others.

You can't just try and override the styling like this. The editor is in complete control of the styling of the text and will ignore any changes you make. The `Reconciler`, for example, runs in the background updating every half second.

You must look at the particular editor and see what facilities it offers to add to its styling system.

You may be able to use the `IMarker` interface if you just want to mark errors and warnings.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.
I thought the issue was something along these lines... Do you maybe have an example (or a link to an example) of how I can dynamically highlight code?

Comment: As I said it depends on the editor. For the Java editor [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13802131/2670892) has some answers.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html . Just remember that Markers are for the file and contents on disk, Annotations are fine for just being in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [Annotations](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors_annotations.htm&cp=2_0_13_3) from the [Annotations extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_editors_markerAnnotationSpecification.html) instead. At least [those are used by the Eclemma plugin](https://github.com/jacoco/eclemma/blob/master/com.mountainminds.eclemma.ui/src/com/mountainminds/eclemma/internal/ui/annotation/CoverageAnnotation.java) to display different color background in the Java editor.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! Would Annotations allow the colouring of individual syntax characters? I have been experimenting with IMarkers, but I can't get them to do what I want due to lack of available information online.

Comment: A range of 1 character is surely possible. About the available customizations I'm not sure. But you can try yourself. Open the "Annotations" preference page (underneath "text editors"). Select one of the annotations you know and can easily reproduce in your IDE and then play around with the "text as" dropbox on the right of the preference page to see the available styles.